# Using setTimeout with Canvas to Print Text from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, text, canvas, settimeout

Good day, Programmer:

I am looking to print out a series of strings, from an array, onto a canvas. Currently, it does not clear the canvas *and* prints all the text in a single iteration.

```
var test1 = ["This","is","a","test","to","see","if","it","really","works"];

function printWord(i){
    setTimeout( function(){ ctx.fillText(test1[i], 150, 90) }, 1000 ) }

function clearScreen(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 100);
}

function playText(){
    for(var i = 0; i < test1.length; i++){
        clearScreen;
        printWord(i);
    };
}
playText();
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLCreatini/W8w2f/11/). Updated link, thanks to Bigood for fixing the timing.
Still require help with clearing the canvas.

Thank you,

LLCreatini

Comment: You have a `clearScreen` here in `playText` function, but not in the fiddle. Mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that your loop was calling all those timeouts at once, not delaying the call. Instead, you need an interval and then clear it when you're finished with the array (I took some inspiration from this: [setTimeout inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776687/settimeout-inside-for-loop)). Here's a modified example, using the same approach as the link I posted:

```
var test1 = ["This","is","a","test","to","see","if","it","really","works."];

var c = document.getElementById("screen"); //Setup screen.
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");   
ctx.font = "normal 42px Arial";
ctx.textAlign= "center";
var i = 0;

function clearScreen(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 100);
}

var timer = setInterval(function(){
    clearScreen();
    ctx.fillText(test1[i], 150, 91);
    i++; 
    if(i >= test1.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 200);

timer();
```

And here's a link to the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8w2f/18/)

Comment: Thank you so much, Gary. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Your script isn't printing everything in one iteration : in fact, the callback of your timeouts are called as many time as you asked (put a breakpoint to verify that).

**The main problem here is that you initiate all the timeouts in the same time (with a few milliseconds of delay), so they all trigger at the same time.**

To resolve this, you could use the `index` to set different timeouts for each word :

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    ctx.fillText(test1[index], 150, 91);
}, 200 * index );  //Multiply by index, it'll trigger at 200ms, 400ms, 600ms...
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8w2f/13/) for a demonstration!

---

### Edit

If you want to clean the screen between each word, call your method `clearScreen` in the timeout, as following :

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    clearScreen();
    ctx.fillText(test1[index], 150, 91);
}, 200 * index );
```

[Here is a demonstration of this.](http://jsfiddle.net/W8w2f/20/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Bigood. Do you know how to make the clearScreen() work?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the for loop, the index of array can be handle by `setTimeout()` something like.

```
function printWord(index){
    setTimeout( function(){ 
        if(index < test1.length){
            ctx.fillText(test1[index], 150, 91);
            index++
            printWord(index);        
        }

    }, 1000);
}

function playText(){
   printWord(0);
}
playText();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W8w2f/19/)

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two separate problems: Adding a delay between each text and clearing the canvas

**Delay between each text**

`setTimeout` is not blocking as in most other languages; code after the setTimeout statement will run before the timeout has hit.

Your code basically run `printWord` 10 times in a row, without any delay, with a different index, which will cause your `setTimeout` functions to be run at the same time.

If you need to have a delay, you can't use a regular for loop. You either have to multiply the delay with `i`, or do it this way (which I think looks more clean):

```
var i = 0;
function playNextText(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        printWord(i);

        i++;
        if(i < test1.length)
            //There are more texts left
            playNextText();
    }, 200);
}
playNextText();
```

**Clearing the drawing area**

Your other problem is very simple;

```
context.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
```

A complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/EUz7T/2/

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you already made the clearScreen function. Just call it before drawing the text just as I did instead of clearing in the draw function